# Wordpress Divi Theme Format

Tags: wordpress, themes

so I'm building out a non-profit website using divi theme, I know they have their own support forums, but I do not have an active subscription that can ask for support.

My problem: It's a scaling problem from switch to different platforms, an example would be, I develop on a 15" laptop and a side monitor that is 21", I mainly build it on my side monitor because it's big and nice, but once I switch it over to my laptop screen, it's just terrible.

Website : http://potenzadevelopment.com/livingspringsfaith-PC/

I don't fully understand what's happening, I understand the website is responsive, which is great, but I want it to look the same on every platform.

I looked up some examples, like : http://theartofwhy.com/ 
Once I resize the browser, everything is fine and nice, I don't know how to fix this problem.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well looks like there are a few issues here, firstly the padding/margins needs to be reduced on large text elements but also it would appear you are using quite an old version of the theme.  I would pay for the latest theme.

There are a lot of issues on this page and it does fall outside the scope of a question to simply answer... however I would advise re-creating the rows with in divi and try to make some elements larger on smaller screens i.e. make width 100% on tablet where it is currently 50%.

Or copy the rows that look bad and set them to not be visible on mobile or tablets and then set up a row that is visible on tablets and mobile

Hope that makes sense